# when ever go live with my react project with Go Live this will happen anfd my project re not open on browser

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

when ever I open my react project in vs code with brave browser with Go Live i don't konw why live server are not work properly and i not dont understand properly what happened in vs code in setting this will happen

I was check their path and it is right on path but my project show this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

React is not like HTML which you can run with GoLive extension. To run react you need nodejs installed on your system.
after you install the nodejs on your pc.

Then you have to run a command in your project root on terminal.

```
npm start
```

if you have installed nodejs correctly then it will open your react application on `localhost:300`

`you can't run your react aplication with GoLive vc code extension`